# Next Js Server Erorr for Expired Time

Tags: next.js, next.js14, clerk

What is the **permanent solution** for this:

Server Error
**Error**: *Clerk*: Clock skew detected. This usually means that your system clock is inaccurate. Clerk will continuously try to issue new tokens, as the existing ones will be treated as "expired" due to clock skew.

To resolve this issue, make sure your system's clock is set to the correct time (e.g. turn off and on automatic time synchronization).

I tried refresh, hard refresh and server restart. My date is on automatic.

Comment: You say you want a **permanent** solution - does that mean you found a **temporary** solution? Which one?
Which OS are you on? For WSL2 on Windows, [the solutions in this github issue](https://github.com/adrianhajdin/threads/issues/86) might help

Comment: Well, first of all, is your system time correct?